What could be the need/use of Executors#newThreadPerTaskExecutor?
I was going through few recently introduced public APIs and stumbled upon Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor in JDK 21+.

Creates an Executor that starts a new Thread for each task. The number
of threads created by the Executor is unbounded.

But from certain references, I had learned that before virtual threads, developers would be restricted to creating a limited number of threads. Sure, with virtual threads we want the devs to be not bothered about such limitations but creation via newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor  would anyway provide the unbounded executor that one might require.
I further quote from the JEP-444 (emphasis mine):

Additionally, Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(ThreadFactory) and
Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() create an ExecutorService
that creates a new thread for each task. These methods enable
migration and interoperability with existing code that uses thread
pools and ExecutorService.


I could not think of a use case, where the migration would seek the usage of the newThreadPerTaskExecutor API. My thoughts considering migration of existing code were that in cases there was an existing ThreadFactory supplied to an instance, it could be now easily replaced with
Thread.ofVirtual().name("vt-").factory()

and any new creation can take the route of newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor. Is there something I am missing out here or could this end up being an overlooked API with misuses more than its usefulness in migration?
Couldn't really find code references to look into where this would be helping with the current documentation except that newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor internally invokes it as follows:
public static ExecutorService newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadFactory factory = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();
    return newThreadPerTaskExecutor(factory);
}

which could have been written self-sufficiently as:
public static ExecutorService newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadFactory factory = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();
    return ThreadPerTaskExecutor.create(threadFactory);
}


I don't think it is as much about migration as it is about customizing of ThreadFactory  for virtual threads. With newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor , as it is currently declared, there is no way to customize ThreadFactory  for virtual threads.

@igor.zh True, but that could have easily been an overloaded method public static ExecutorService newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory){...}. The current API declaration seems to be doing something other than the virtual threads too.

Sure, it certainly could have been, but if you look at Executors class as a whole, not only from a standpoint of virtual threads, you will notice that it already has a lot of methods. This is a classic eternal API trade-off.  I think that the designers decided that virtual threads are not that big of a deal to add 3 methods to this class instead of two. They provided bare minimum that allows to do everything with virtual threads-based Executors and considered the job done.

@Naman It wouldn't have been logical to create it as an overload of newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor, because a ThreadFactory also allows you to create platform threads, so having virtual in the method would then be potentially incorrect and thus confusing. The name newThreadPerTaskExecutor covers exactly what it does. So, if you want to, you can use platform threads, even if it might not be advisable.

@MarkRotteveel Yes, I get that. But more of what I meant from the previous comment was that for customization towards newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor, there wasn't a need for a whole new API such as newThreadPerTaskExecutor or could that be the case if I am further missing out on anything?

@Naman Yes, you're missing that this exposes a flexible API that will allow you to provide a configured thread factory (virtual or platform!), with configuration for specific thread names, whether or not thread locals should be inherited, and configuring the (default) uncaught exception handler, and for platform threads only, whether they are daemon, their thread group, priority, stack size.

The “create a new thread per task” policy doesn’t say anything about the absolute number of threads it’ll create. The elephant in the room is the dependence on the number of tasks ever submitted to it. So any scenario with either, a low total number of tasks or a low number of tasks existing concurrently, might be fine with such a policy. N.B. my Windows machine has no problem with a process creating 100,000 platform threads. Creating that many thread might not be the best option performance-wise, but this doesn’t mean that it’s always the worst thing to do.

@Holger Since that would have been possible with fixedThreadPool(nThreads) as well. I am considering that introducing the API will shape developers to use the underlying ThreadPerTaskExecutor more often than the earlier ThreadPoolExecutor. Would that be a correct inference?
@MarkRotteveel IMHO, the customization part is more of an add-on that could have been possible with existing APIs too, and without exposing an API risking JVMs being impacted by OOM.

How is that even remotely the same? fixedThreadPool will, as the name suggests, keep the specified number of threads alive whereas newThreadPerTaskExecutor will never reuse a thread.

@Holger No, not the same. However, creating 100,000 platform threads would be feasible with the help of the fixedThreadPool API. I think what most of this hints towards is that with the newThreadPerTaskExecutor fresh threads can be created per task required to be performed. Based upon the need, if the task is I/O extensive, one shall select the thread type to be a virtual thread and if not, stay with the platform threads itself.

I never said that creating 100,000 platform threads was a goal. I provided this number, so you can better judge the actual risks of a newThreadPerTaskExecutor potentially creating a few thousand threads (when you submit a few thousand tasks at the same time). Of course, you can configure a thread pool executor to have practically no limit on the non core threads to get a similar risk. But you don’t use newThreadPerTaskExecutor to get that risk but to get the guaranty that each task runs in a fresh new thread. Which the other executors do not provide.
